# Dropdown List in MVC 4 binding to model (must be a better way than this!)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently using ViewBag to get data from a View to update my model. I'm using a dropdownlist from which I'm getting the selected item and in my controller updating my "customer model" with the selection. I know this is not a good way to do it... please tell me how to achieve updating my "customer model" with the dropdownlist selection without using the formcollection parameters.

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Customer customer, FormCollection form)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get selectected title from dropdownlist
            customer.Title = form["TitleDropDownList"];

            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(customer);
    }
```

**View**

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("TitleDropDownList")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**My Get Method is...**

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        // Create title dropdownlist list for new customers
        List<SelectListItem> titleDropDownList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        titleDropDownList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mr", Value = "Mr" });
        titleDropDownList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mrs", Value = "Mrs" });
        titleDropDownList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Miss", Value = "Miss" });
        titleDropDownList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Ms", Value = "Ms" });
        ViewBag.TitleDropDownList = titleDropDownList;

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: can you post your `[HttpGet]` method as well?

Comment: just add the TitleDropDownList property to your Model (Customer)

Answer (score 0):

if you change your method to be static and return List

```
public static List<SelectListItem> Create(){
    //Build List
    return titleDropDownList;
}
```

you can change your dropdown on the view to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Title, PathToController.Create(), "Select One")
```

Hopefully this helps.